# Howto read file into collection string to create a xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, arraylist, io

frist i want to read and store informations about persons from simple txt files.

files look like this e.g.

```
person=3
name=Tigan 
sirname=Cenk 
id=1231 
nationality=whatever
name2=Joo
sirname2=Boo 
id2=1299
nationality2=whatever
<optinal>=whatever
name3=Joo
sirname3=Boo 
id3=1211
nationality3=whatever
```

i create a person class like the following exapmle:

```
class Person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string sirname { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nationality { get; set; }
     }
```

then the following code to read the lines from the files:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path2File).ToList();
List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
```

after that i split the lines with the delimeter "="

```
foreach (var line in lines)
   {
   Char delimiter = '=';
   string[] contents = line.Split(delimiter);
   }
```

Now my question is, how can i past contents"[1]"(e.g.Tigan) to the right place on my collection array contetns"[0]" (e.g.name or name1) to person.name

i need to return list with all the data to use it for creating a xml.

i hope someone can help me.

kind regards.

Comment: Can you change the text files? Using json would be much simpler.

Comment: Does each text file contain only 1 person? or is it one big text file with many people and info in it?

Comment: @HebeleHododo - no i cant change the text files, they have to stay.

Comment: @Fuzzybear - files can contain 1 or more persons (unlimited)

Comment: Is there a delimiter between each person in the file then?and do they all have the same data associated with each person? or are there lines missing.  ie would sirname2= be a line on it's own for a blank?

Comment: @Fuzzybear - there is no delimeter between each person. all elements are equal for each person. if one value is missing the elements appairs with no value (e.g. sirname= ). BUT, 1 element can appair if there is a value for it (e.g. postalcode). Therefore some of the persons have 4 and some of the other persons can have 5 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks both for support! if anyone is interested, here is one possible solution i used:

```
    var person = new Person();
    for (int i=1; i < lines.Count; i+=12)
        {
            if (lines[i].StartsWith("name"))
            {
                person.name = lines[i].Split('=')[1];

            }
            if (lines[i+1].StartsWith("sirname"))
            {
                person.sirname = lines[i+1].Split('=')[1];

            } 
            if (lines[i+2].StartsWith("id"))
            {
                person.id = lines[i+2].Split('=')[1];

            }
            if (lines[i+3].StartsWith("nationality"))
            {
                person.nationality = lines[i+3].Split('=')[1];

            }
            try //optional element
            {
                if (lines[i + 4].StartsWith("whatever"))
                {
                    person.whatever = lines[i + 4].Split('=')[1];
                    i += 1;
                    list.Add(person);
                    person = new Person();
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    break; //fileformat not supported
                }
           catch 
           {
                list.Add(person);
                person = new Person();
            }
        }
```

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=1; i < lines.Length; i+=4)
{
    Person person = new Person();
    person.name = lines[i].Split('=')[1];
    person.sirname = lines[i+1].Split('=')[1];
    person.id = lines[i+2].Split('=')[1];
    person.nationality = lines[i+3].Split('=')[1];

    list.Add(person);
}
```

You can loop the lines with 4 elements gap and in the loop take all 4 lines and add them to person class. You **must start the loop of lines with index 1**, because your first element is not part of the class !

Comment: nice approach. i just have to handle some persons which have more than just 4 elements. e.g. some of them have a postalcode as the last element. i try to solve it will give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this:

```
var person = new Person();
foreach (var line in lines)
   {
   Char delimiter = '=';
   string[] contents = line.Split(delimiter);
   switch(contents[0])       
      {         
         case "id":  
            if(person.id != Convert.ToInt32(contents[1]) && person.name != null)
               {
                   list.Add(person);
                   person = new Person();
               }
            person.id = Convert.ToInt32(contents[1]);
            break;  
         case "name ":   
            person.name = contents[1];
            break;  
         case "sirname":            
            person.sirname = contents[1];
            break; 
        //...etc
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your approch! But i dont get how that part will work:                     `case "person":  
            if(person.id != Convert.ToInt32(contents[1]))  
               {  
                   list.Add(person);  
                   person = new Person();  
               }  
            person.id = Convert.ToInt32(contents[1]);  
            break;`     in your case it will compare 3 with the id of any person and it will not match. so all list are empty because person is the first element of the file.

Comment: Ah sorry i assumed the person at the top was unique for each person I see it needs to be the id.  I 'll edit my answer, just needs to check for case "id"

Comment: Sorry nope seen another issue with it, let me have another look

Comment: @CenkTigan Ok that should be better now, by checking && person.name != null you should now only add completely filled person class.

Comment: thanks! one more problem is that cases dont match after one person, because the name of one element e.g name change to name1 for the 2nd person. now i realized it with if clauses :  `if (contents[0].StartsWith("name"))
                {
                    person.name = contents[1];
                }
                if (contents[0].StartsWith("sirname"))
                {
                    person.sirname = contents[1];
                }
                if (contents[0].StartsWith("id"))
                {
                    person.id = contents[1];
                }`

Comment: Your most welcome @CenkTigan Ah i see your lables change in the text files to going through each person, yes you will need to use if statements here as can not look for string.contains in a switch statement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918176/use-an-objects-string-contains-method-within-a-switch-statement But you should be able to use If as u have said.